# Why does this SocketServer work in Python but not IronPython?

Tags: c#, python, .net, ironpython, socketserver

I'm writing a small socket server to wrap around a .NET/C# API. I'm having trouble to get it to work when the SocketServer runs under IronPython. I'm using version 2.7.4.

When I run the server like this:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe data_server.py
```

From the client I get the output I expect:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe data_client.py
{'host': ('localhost', 31337), 'name': 'A'}
{'host': ('localhost', 31337), 'name': 'B'}
{'host': ('localhost', 31337), 'name': 'C'}
```

But when I run the server using IronPython, I get nothing from the client. I.e.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\ipy64.exe" ipdb_server.py
```

I have tried 32/64bit IronPython and running the client with 32/64 bit IronPython. Whatever way I do it, the IronPython server doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

### Python code

The server code looks like this:

```
# data_server.py
import sys, os, pickle, SocketServer
PORT = 31337

def dump_data(f):
    for w in ['A','B','C']: # test data to be replaced by call to .NET API
        meta = {}
        meta['name'] = w
        print 'Sending: ', meta
        pickle.dump(meta, f)

class DataHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        f = self.request.makefile()
        dump_data(f)
        f.close()

SocketServer.TCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True
serv = SocketServer.TCPServer(("",PORT), DataHandler)
print "server running on port %d" % PORT
serv.serve_forever()
```

The client code looks like this:

```
# data_client
import pickle, socket

def get_data(host):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(host)
    f = s.makefile()

    try:
        while True:
            meta = pickle.load(f)
            meta['host'] = host
            yield meta
    except EOFError:
        pass
    f.close()
    s.close()

data = get_data(("localhost",31337))
for d in data: print d
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I can answer my own question. It turns out that I had to change the call to socket.makefile to explicitly specify binary mode. I.e.:

```
f = self.request.makefile('b')
```

I assume that this is down to a subtly different implementation in IronPython.